# Unit-testing JDBI Mapper with ResultSet and StatementContext as parameters

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit4, jdbi

I have to write a unit-test for the following method in `class VPartnerExtMapper` *(VPartnerExtMapper.java)*:

```
import org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.RowMapper;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.StatementContext;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class VPartnerExtMapper implements RowMapper<VPartnerExt> {
  @Override
  public VPartnerExt map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
    int i = 1;
    VPartnerExt result = new VPartnerExt();

    result.setTecClient(rs.getLong(i++));
    result.setPartnerId(rs.getLong(i++));
    result.setTecVersionNr(rs.getLong(i++));
    result.setName(rs.getString(i++));
   
    return result;
  }
}
```

**My code for the unit-test so far** *(VPartnerExtMapperTest.java)* **:**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class VPartnerExtMapperTest {
  @Mock
  private ResultSet resultSet;

  @Mock
  StatementContext ctx;

  @Test
  public void map() throws SQLException {

    ResultSet resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);

    when(resultSet.getString("NAME")).thenReturn("Michael");

    VPartnerExt result = new VPartnerExtMapper().map(resultSet, ctx);
    assertEquals("Michael", result.getName());
  }
}
```

(Please let me know if I missed something and need to put it in the explanation before downgrading the question.)